# MySQL date calculation in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

I want to get a statistic of registered users per month for the past year, so I constructed this query

```
SELECT MONTH(created_at) as m, COUNT(*) as c
FROM users
WHERE created_at >= DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH), '%Y-%m')
GROUP BY m
```

Now what I understand MySQL will do is

- Select all rows
- Perform conditional check - if field `created_at` is gte to `DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH), '%Y-%m')` add row to temporary table, else disregard it
- Group rows based on the derived column `m`
- Count rows in each group and put them in derived column `c`

If supposedly what I said above is correct, I am concerned about point 2. In a typical program the value in the if statement will be calculated every time if not put in a variable.

Do I need to put the statement `DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH), '%Y-%m')` in a variable and reference that in my `WHERE` clause to keep it from recalculating it on each row, and how?

Comment: I am not sure exactly what MySQL will do here. It would appear that you have created a string containing the year and month and are comparing that to a DATETIME field. If so then MySQL will probably convert the month / year string to a datetime before the comparison which should perform OK (assuming an index on created_at).

Answer (score 1):

While executing your query the very first part that will be considered is the `where` clause. After that `group by` and then It will select all those resulting rows.

You don'y need to add any extra variables you just talked about at the end